# Symfony FOSUserBundle link to reset password

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

- I need to add a link to reset password for a user in my admin panel.
- I have a list of users and when I click on one user I want to send new password or password change request.

How would I do this?

Comment: Can't you add some more details ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you seem new to Symfony, welcome - we have all been there.

<kbd>1.</kbd> Figuring out the route to reset a password.

Symfony has a very helpful command line for you to debug routes from the command line.

```
php app/console router:debug | grep fos_user
```

This shows you the route for users to reset their password is the following:

```
  fos_user_resetting_request   GET   ANY  ANY   /resetting/request
```

<kbd>2.</kbd> Sending an email.

That's super easy with Symfony, use Swift Mailer. [How to send an email?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html)

Comment: Thank you for your explaination :)